# Sync audio time using microphone [Android root/noroot]

Tags: audio, sync, microphone

My TV(not a smart TV) speaker is playing an audio, I had the same audio in my android phone(rooted). How to sync both audios without any external/wireless connection, and with the help of syncing using android phone's microphone. so that after syncing i can reduce TV volume and hear audio from my android (using headphones or phone speaker)

Comment: I didn't gave them a try, but might be worth a look: there are [some apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_network#group_1125) promising a solution for this, like SnapCast and AmpMe. With some luck they solve your issue (if so, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with some details on how they worked out). Best luck!

Comment: Nothing is working . The problem is,  my TV doesn't have any connection with my phone , means no Bluetooth , no wifi and no hdmi , and i only want my phone to listen the audio of my TV and play same audio that i saved in my android. here audio means any maybe music or a movie audio track.